# create a reference to an string (Blazor)

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm doing a Blazor app, although I have the impression the question is C# and independent to blazor.

I have a class with some strings (like `Person.Name, Person.Surname, etc`)

I have a person viewer component that shows those strings. And a "string editor" component so when the user clicks on the name of the patient, the string editor component will appear and allow you to edit the name (It is not exactly like that, but will help us simplify the scenario and find a solution)

The question is how to send a reference to `Person.Name` to the StringEditor component, so the original string is also edited when it is edited there. If I was an object is simple, you send the object and just a reference is sent so changes done in the component apply to the original source object but for strings... this does not work like this. A copy is sent, and the changes are not carried over to the original component.

The scenario would look a bit like :

Person class

```
public class Person{
   public string Name {get;set;} = "";
   public string Surname {get;set;} = "";
}
```

Main razor component

```
<div>
  <div @onclick=()=>{OpenStringEditor(user.Name)}>@user.Name</div>
  <div @onclick=()=>{OpenStringEditor(user.Surname)}>@user.Surname</div>
</div>
<div class=@(ShowEditor ? "ShowEditor" : "HideEditor")>
  <StringEditor StringToEdit EditFinished=whenFinished/>
</div>
code{
  [Parameter] pubic Person user {get; set;}
  private void OpenStringEditor(string ToEdit)
  {
    StringToEdit = ToEdit; // This is where I'd need to keep a reference 
                           // to the original source, so when the
                           // edit is finished I can store the end product
    ShowEditor = true;
  }

  private void whenFinished()
  {
    Person.StoreToDB(); //whatever
    ShowEditor = false;
  }
}
```

StringEditor

```
<input @bind=ToBeEdited @onfocusout=EditFinished />
code
{
  [Parameter] public string ToBeEdited;
  [Parameter] public EventCallback EditFinished;
}
```

So you see, this would work for objects, but not for raw strings

I guess the bottom question would be: how to keep a reference of "where to store the changes when the edit is finished."

Comment: strings are immutable in C# so you cannot edit the string.

Comment: this is exactly what I'm asking, how to move around this limitation

Comment: It's not a limitation. All C# programs manipulate strings one way or another. Strings are reference types, so `a reference to a string` isn't very clear - you already have a reference to a string.

Comment: I guess the bottom question would be: how to keep a reference of "where to store the changes when the edit is finished."

Comment: If this was C++ I would just keep a pointer to the string being asked to modify and when the edit is finished store the end product on the pointer source. How to solve that in C#

Comment: You already have a reference. Browsers don't work that way. You should phrase the question without any reference to ... references. JavaScript and java strings are immutable too. The UI elements aren't tied to some specific memory location. Changes to the UI elements are read by JS/WASM/C# code and processed one way or another. Displaying a string in a multi-line edit means copying/rendering that data at the browser level

Comment: I used the word reference because on methods you can do `MyMethod(ref string str)` and this would do exactly what I asked for. Store the changes in the original place. I want to replicate this behavior. Hence, the wording.

Comment: That's the wrong mental model. Browsers don't work that way. Not just Blazor, but JS apps in general. React, Vue, Angular *and* Blazor work through properties, callbacks etc, not direct memory references. You should start with any SPA framework to see how things work instead of trying to apply a low-level C-style model to JS and HTML.

Comment: Similar to most SPAs (if not all) data in Blazor is passed to components through model properties bound to component parameters. When a property changes, the SPA framework notifies the component to redraw itself. When the data changes, the framework updates the property with the changes. With a string property that means replacing the contents. What you ask is similar to many Popup/Modal examples. A display *and* an invisible editor component are bound to the same text property. When it's time to edit, the editor is displayed.

Comment: I would gladly accept another approach that leads to a string editor where I can send strings to be modified. I just wrote I was trying so far because people at SO usually want that.

Comment: My problem with standard approach is that `<input>` cannot be css'd to "auto" width, witch is mandatory in my design.  And <span> with contenteditable tab won't fire onfocusout so I cannot fire my "store to DB" method when edit is finished. That's why I ended up with a div that opens an external editor, where I can have a input with fixed width not destroying my layout

Comment: That's what all Modal/Popup form samples show. They don't need string references. CSS and spans have nothing to do with database operations. What you try to do is described in the [ASP.NET Core Blazor forms and input components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-and-input-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0). The form itself can be inside a [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) that appears only when an element is clicked. That won't change how the change events are handled

Comment: Instead of trying to do everything at once, try using a plain old form first. Then put that form into a component. Once that works, only then add a Modal inside that component. This way your main page won't have to change or even know how the Editor does its job. The [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) examples show that actually showing a Modal is "only" extra divs and classes around the INPUT elements

Comment: I know how to do all that. But I cannot accommodate input fields in my design. Because those need fixed widths.

Answer (score 0):

Do this fit the bill?

First you need a Modal Dialog Framework.  I've included a simple one - the code is in appendix to this answer, but you can use any of those available that are suitable.

A "Text Editor" component which we will use in the modal dialog.  If you're editing other data types you will need different ones.  It interacts with the cascaded instance of the Modal Dialog wrapper.

#### TextEditor.razor

```cs
<div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label small text-muted">@this.Label</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" value="@this.Value" @oninput=this.Changed />
        <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick=Exit>Set</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick=Cancel>Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private IModalDialog? Modal { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Label { get; set; } = "Field";
    [Parameter] public string? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }

    private string? _value;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => _value = Value;

    private void Changed(ChangeEventArgs e)
    => this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(e.Value?.ToString() ?? null);

    private void Exit()
        => Modal?.Close(ModalResult.OK());

    private async Task Cancel()
    {
        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_value);
        Modal?.Close(ModalResult.Cancel());
    }
}
```

And then our "Special Format" page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1 class="mb-5">Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="mt-5 mb-5" >
    Editor
</div>

<div class="mt-5 border border-1 border-dark p-1" style="cursor:pointer;" @onclick="() => Edit(CountryModalOptions)">
    @model.Country
</div>

<div class="mt-2 border border-1 border-dark p-1" style="cursor:pointer;" @onclick="() => Edit(ContinentModalOptions)">
    @model.Continent
</div>

<BaseModalDialog @ref=this.Modal />

@code {
    private IModalDialog? Modal;
    private Model model = new();

    private async Task Edit(ModalOptions options)
    {
        if (Modal is not null)
        {
            var result = await Modal.ShowAsync<TextEditor>(options);
            // do things
        }
    }

    private ModalOptions CountryModalOptions
    {
        get
        {
            var options = new ModalOptions();
            options.ControlParameters.Add("Label", "Field Name");
            options.ControlParameters.Add("Value", model.Country);
            options.ControlParameters.Add("ValueChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create<String>(this, RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this, __value => model.Country = __value, model.Country)));
            options.ControlParameters.Add("ValueExpression", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<System.String>>>(() => model.Country));
            return options;
        }
    }

    private ModalOptions ContinentModalOptions
    {
        get
        {
            var options = new ModalOptions();
            options.ControlParameters.Add("Label", "Field Name");
            options.ControlParameters.Add("Value", model.Continent);
            options.ControlParameters.Add("ValueChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create<String>(this, RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this, __value => model.Continent = __value, model.Continent)));
            options.ControlParameters.Add("ValueExpression", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<System.String>>>(() => model.Continent));
            return options;
        }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public string Country { get; set; } = "No Country Set";
        public string Continent { get; set; } = "No Continent Set";
    }
}
```

So what's going on.

We have our `BaseModalDialog` component registered on the page with a global variable reference.  When you click on an editable field the onclick handler opens the modal dialog by calling `ShowAsync`.  It sets the component as `T` and passes in a set of Parameters to apply to `T` when it's defined.  The standard bind Parameters are mapped to the model field using some RuntimeHelpers.

The dialog opens and you can edit the value.  I've wired it up to update on each keypress (oninput).  Click on either `Set` or `Cancel` to exit the model as pass "control" back to the main page.

I've kept everything as basic as I can, there are all sorts of Css and formating options you can apply to improve the UX.

## Appendix The Modal Dialog

### ModalOptions

```cs
public sealed class ModalOptions : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
{
    public string Width { get; set; } = "50%";
    public Dictionary<string, object> ControlParameters { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var item in ControlParameters)
            yield return item;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => this.GetEnumerator();

    public T? Get<T>(string key)
    {
        if (this.ControlParameters.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            if (this.ControlParameters[key] is T t) return t;
        }
        return default;
    }

    public bool TryGet<T>(string key, [NotNullWhen(true)] out T? value)
    {
        value = default;
        if (this.ControlParameters.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            if (this.ControlParameters[key] is T t)
            {
                value = t;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool Set(string key, object value)
    {
        if (this.ControlParameters.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            this.ControlParameters[key] = value;
            return false;
        }
        this.ControlParameters.Add(key, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

### ModalResult

```cs
public enum ModalResultType { NoSet, OK, Cancel, Exit }

public sealed class ModalResult
{
    public ModalResultType ResultType { get; private set; } = ModalResultType.NoSet;
    public object? Data { get; set; } = null;

    public static ModalResult OK() => new ModalResult() { ResultType = ModalResultType.OK };
    public static ModalResult Exit() => new ModalResult() { ResultType = ModalResultType.Exit };
    public static ModalResult Cancel() => new ModalResult() { ResultType = ModalResultType.Cancel };
    public static ModalResult OK(object data) => new ModalResult() { Data = data, ResultType = ModalResultType.OK };
    public static ModalResult Exit(object data) => new ModalResult() { Data = data, ResultType = ModalResultType.Exit };
    public static ModalResult Cancel(object data) => new ModalResult() { Data = data, ResultType = ModalResultType.Cancel };
}
```

### IModalDialog

```cs
public interface IModalDialog
{
    public ModalOptions Options { get; }
    public bool IsActive { get; }
    public bool Display { get; }
    public Task<ModalResult> ShowAsync<TModal>(ModalOptions options) where TModal : IComponent;
    public void Dismiss();
    public void Close(ModalResult result);
    public void Update(ModalOptions? options = null);
}
```

### BaseModalDialog.razor

```cs
@namespace Blazr.UI
@implements IModalDialog

@if (this.Display)
{
    <CascadingValue Value="(IModalDialog)this">
        <div class="base-modal-background">
            <div class="base-modal-content" style="width:@this.Options.Width;" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                <DynamicComponent Type=this.ModalContentType Parameters=this.Options.ControlParameters />
            </div>
        </div>
    </CascadingValue>
}

@code {
    public ModalOptions Options { get; protected set; } = new ModalOptions();
    public bool Display { get; protected set; }
    public bool IsActive => this.ModalContentType is not null;
    protected TaskCompletionSource<ModalResult> _ModalTask { get; set; } = new TaskCompletionSource<ModalResult>();
    protected Type? ModalContentType = null;

    public Task<ModalResult> ShowAsync<TModal>(ModalOptions options) where TModal : IComponent
    {
        this.ModalContentType = typeof(TModal);
        this.Options = options ??= this.Options;
        this._ModalTask = new TaskCompletionSource<ModalResult>();
        this.Display = true;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        return this._ModalTask.Task;
    }

    public void Update(ModalOptions? options = null)
    {
        this.Options = options ??= this.Options;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public async void Dismiss()
    {
        this._ModalTask.TrySetResult(ModalResult.Cancel());
        await Reset();
    }

    public async void Close(ModalResult result)
    {
        this._ModalTask.TrySetResult(result);
        await Reset();
    }

    private async Task Reset()
    {
        this.Display = false;
        this.ModalContentType = null;
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```

### BaseModalDialog.razor.css

```css
div.base-modal-background {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 101; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

div.base-modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #888;
    width: 50%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: how do you start the modal linked to a certain string ?

Comment: The Wrapper Modal Dialog component is  setup on the page like this: `<BaseModalDialog @ref=this.Modal />` and captured as a global variable in the main page. `var result = await Modal.ShowAsync<TextEditor>(options);` then opens the dialog with the specified component and parameters applied.  I've temporarily put a demo project on Github that you can download and run to see things in action - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO74849147 - I'll leave it up for a few days.